# What is the default value of initialDelaySeconds?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

Kubernetes' liveness and readiness probes for pods (deployment) can be configured with this initial delay ---- meaning the probe will start after this many seconds after the container is up. If it is not specified, what is the default value? I can't seem to find it. The default value for periodSeconds is documented as 10 second.

Thanks

Comment: InitialDelaySeconds is `0`.

Comment: If this were 0, the liveness check would easily fail as services normally take time to be live. When liveness fail, the containers will be restarted. The liveness check would fail again cause the containers to restart again. This does not seem to happen with our service where we have not set initialDelaySeconds. Our service definitely takes a few seconds to go live.

Comment: I searched the Kubernetes source code but could seem to find how this is handled when it is not set.

Comment: If it is not specified, default value is zero. Because, when json/yaml is unmarshaled into go struct, if you not set, it will be zero.

Comment: @RyanDing, after 0s probes will be executed 3 times after waiting for 10s. so if your app is live after 30s the liveness probe succeeds.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It seems that the default value of `0` is missing from the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#configure-probes).

The health or readiness check algorithm works like this:

1. Wait for `initialDelaySeconds`
2. Perform readiness check and wait `timeoutSeconds` for a timeout
3. If the number of continued successes is greater than `successThreshold` return `success`
   If the number of continued failures is greater than `failureThreshold` return `failure`
   otherwise wait `periodSeconds` and start a new readiness check

Comment: Looks like the docs link is busted. This has current with defaults: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#configure-probes

Answer (score 23):

Given the pace at which the project changes, I wanted to make sure the code actually confirms this.

Found a test in the public Kubernetes repo that verifies the default settings for probes:

```
    expectedProbe := v1.Probe{
        InitialDelaySeconds: 0,
        TimeoutSeconds:      1,
        PeriodSeconds:       10,
        SuccessThreshold:    1,
        FailureThreshold:    3,
    }
```

See method `TestSetDefaultProbe` in

> https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/apis/core/v1/defaults_test.go

Answer (score 2):

Default value of **initialDelaySeconds** is **0** as per the current Documentation.

For Ref - [Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#configure-probes)

[image]

Comment: The docs also say that the initial delay is ignored if it is less then the period:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#configure-probes

"If the value of periodSeconds is greater than initialDelaySeconds then the initialDelaySeconds would be ignored."